# Minimal JPA example without Spring and without XML

Tags: java, hibernate

Java

```
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("provider", "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "username");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/<schema>");

        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("localDB", properties);
```

Gradle dependency

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.3.Final'
```

When I'm running it, I am getting

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named localDB
```

I would like to do it without Spring and without persistence.xml/hibernate.cfg.xml. I am cool with annotation configuration.

I do not know how to declare in properties where is located class with @Entity annotation (without XML).

Where can I find minimal working example with JPA (Hibernate or any other implementation) without XML or additional frameworks (Spring)?

Comment: There is no class named org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence in Hibernate 5.4.3. The persistence provider class is http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider.html.

Comment: Thanks, but still same exception :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes should work fine if you just add a `META-INF/persistence.xml`. However , if you insist doing it without `persistence.xml` , you have to implement `PersistenceUnitInfo` by yourself which is not trivial when comparing to just add a `persistence.xml`. A minimal implementation can be found at [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-jpa-programmatically-without-the-persistence-xml-configuration-file/):

```
public class PersistenceUnitInfoImpl implements PersistenceUnitInfo {

    public static final String JPA_VERSION = "2.1";

    private final String persistenceUnitName;

    private PersistenceUnitTransactionType transactionType = PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL;

    private final List<String> managedClassNames;

    private final List<String> mappingFileNames = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Properties properties;

    private DataSource jtaDataSource;

    private DataSource nonJtaDataSource;

    public PersistenceUnitInfoImpl(
            String persistenceUnitName,
            List<String> managedClassNames,
            Properties properties) {
        this.persistenceUnitName = persistenceUnitName;
        this.managedClassNames = managedClassNames;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistenceUnitName() {
        return persistenceUnitName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistenceProviderClassName() {
        return HibernatePersistenceProvider.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public PersistenceUnitTransactionType getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getJtaDataSource() {
        return jtaDataSource;
    }

    public PersistenceUnitInfoImpl setJtaDataSource(
            DataSource jtaDataSource) {
        this.jtaDataSource = jtaDataSource;
        this.nonJtaDataSource = null;
        transactionType = PersistenceUnitTransactionType.JTA;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getNonJtaDataSource() {
        return nonJtaDataSource;
    }

    public PersistenceUnitInfoImpl setNonJtaDataSource(
            DataSource nonJtaDataSource) {
        this.nonJtaDataSource = nonJtaDataSource;
        this.jtaDataSource = null;
        transactionType = PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getMappingFileNames() {
        return mappingFileNames;
    }

    @Override
    public List<URL> getJarFileUrls() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public URL getPersistenceUnitRootUrl() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getManagedClassNames() {
        return managedClassNames;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean excludeUnlistedClasses() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public SharedCacheMode getSharedCacheMode() {
        return SharedCacheMode.UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
        return ValidationMode.AUTO;
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistenceXMLSchemaVersion() {
        return JPA_VERSION;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTransformer(ClassTransformer transformer) {

    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getNewTempClassLoader() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use it to bootstrap an `EntityManagerFactory`/ `EntityManager` :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "username");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/<schema>");

List<String> entitesClass = new ArrayList<>();
entitesClass.add("com.company.entities.Foo");
entitesClass.add("com.company.entities.Bar");
PersistenceUnitInfoImpl punit = new PersistenceUnitInfoImpl("localDB", entitesClass , properties);

PersistenceProvider provider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
EntityManagerFactory emf= provider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(punit, null);

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
//blablblabl
```